# Adding height to a banana seat

Tags: saddle

I just got an addmotor m-66 r7, I am a bigger rider and am finding I need a just a bit more leg room between me and the pedals to make pedaling enjoyable since the seat is a stationary banana seat.

I was thinking of adding in a spacer of some sort between the seat and the frame to bump up the height of the seat.

Any ideas on a mod to accomplish more height?

[image: addmotor bike]

Comment: It's hard to believe that a bike would be designed with no way to adjust the seat height.  There may be some 3rd party fixes for this, or you could do as you suggest.

Comment: We have over a a century of industry wisdom as to how to build motorbikes and how to build bicycles and how to build electric motors. Seems making an Electric bike that combines that wisdom might take a bit longer yet.

Comment: @DanielRHicks yeah it's an electric scooter with a bench seat, that happens to have pedals and resembles a bicycle.

Comment: @Criggie is right. This bike wasn't meant to be pedaled.

Comment: @AdamRice I honestly doubt the pedals are just decorative. Even the old [Babbettas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babetta) had them and hey were indeed used in some situations. Motorcycle-like mopeds with pedals are nothing new under the sun at all and the pedals are very unlikely to be just an addition due to some way too recent e-bike laws.

Comment: @VladimirF Yes they are connected to the drivetrain, but the primary intention is to use the motor. Hence the footrest for example.

Answer (score 6):

You could try padded cycling shorts/pants, but that would add barely a centimetre.

Re-upholstering the saddle with a thicker cushion might help, but could be fiddly.  Adding a block of wood securely between cushion and frame might work too.

Ultimately the most authorative answer will come from the manufacturer.  I suggest you reach out to them and ask.

- 1-888-660-0868 0730-1800 PST timezone (they are in California, USA)
- Email support@addmotor.com with photos, or even a link to this question
- https://www.addmotor.com/pages/contact-us has a chat-window

I suspect this is more of an electric motorbike with barely-functional "decorative" pedals, and just there to satisfy legal requirements.  The footrest over the bottom bracket makes it seem like pedaling is not the intent.

If you get an answer, do please post back here to share for other future users who may have similar problems.

---

Another thought, if you slide yourself backward on the bench then that may give you more leg room, essentially riding it like a crank-forward bike.  Downside here is the handlebars get further away which might not suit your posture.